# Consulta $ajax "GET" mostrando "undefined"

Tags: ajax, javascript, asp.net-core

Boa noite amigos!
Não tenho experiencia em programação, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Criei uma consulta simples para listar a pesquisa em uma tabela.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnPesquisarPosto").click(function () {
            var termoPesquisa = $("#pesquisaPosto").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/Posto/FiltrarPorNome?pesquisa=" + termoPesquisa,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#tblPosto tbody > tr").remove();
                    $.each(data, function (i, posto) {
                        $("#tblPosto tbody").append(
                            "<tr class='animated fadeIn'>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.Ativo + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.Nome + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.CNPJ + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.InscricaoEstadual + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.DataCadastro + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" + posto.Telefone + "</td>" +
                            "   <td>" +
                            "       <a class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' title='Alterar' href='/Posto/Edit'" + posto.Id + "'><i class='zmdi zmdi-edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" +
                            "       <a class='btn btn-sm btn-success' title='Detalhes' href='/Posto/Details'" + posto.Id + "'><i class='zmdi zmdi-menu' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" +
                            "       <a class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' title='Exluir' href='/Posto/Delete'" + posto.Id + "'><i class='zmdi zmdi-close' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" +
                            "   </td>" +
                            "</tr>"

                        );
                    });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Houve um erro na pesquisa :( ")
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiz o teste com o Postman e está retornando o Json certinho, conforme a busca, porém, na tabela preenche os campos com "undefined".
O método em minha controller não está assíncrono.

Ha! estou usando ASP.NET(full Framework) - MVC 6 - EF7

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FiltrarPorNome(String pesquisa)
    {
        List<Posto> postos = _context.Posto.Where(a => a.Nome.Contains(pesquisa)).ToList();
        List<PostoViewModel> PostoView = Mapper.Map<List<Posto>, List<PostoViewModel>>(postos);
        return Json(PostoView);
    }
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o resultado do seu `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Não sei como anexa outra imagem, upei em outro site. 
Segue o link;

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/erro_console-png--2

Comment: Você está fazendo a referência errada, seu objeto tem as variáveis em minusculo e você está tentando acessar `posto.Ativo` onde o correto seria `posto.ativo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a imagem que você deixou o link, seu objeto tem as variáveis em minusculo e você está tentando acessar `posto.Ativo` onde o correto seria `posto.ativo`

Comment: Realmente era esse o problema. Alterei e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado.